# RxJava: Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter

Tags: rx-java, warnings, rx-java2

Some RxJava methods, such as just, cause Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter warnings.

Why not use @SafeVarargs to solve?

Comment: SafeVarargs is a Java 7 feature and RxJava has to target Java 6 due to Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I still have doubts, is it because @SafeVarargs was added in Android API19?

Comment: We support Android 2.3+, which is API level 9+: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#version-2x-javadoc

Comment: Thank you, I understand.